# Android Listview Floating First Row

Tags: android, facebook, user-interface

I'm trying to find the best way to approach implementing Facebook like floating row on list view

[image: status, photo,checkin]

when scrolling down, the status-photo-checkin disappear to allow more space for the list, and when scrolling up it appears again.
anyone has an idea how can I implement this or direct me to an existing component/library?

Comment: I also want to know that

Comment: That bar on the top has nothing to do with the listview

Comment: gee...I'm embarrassed I haven't figured it out.
So I guess it's a container I should display/hide based on scroll listener

Comment: You can check this git [repo ](https://github.com/amalChandran/twitterListView)with quicl return and pull to refresh.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's called the Quick Return pattern, and Roman's explained it in detail along with an example here:

https://plus.google.com/u/0/+RomanNurik/posts/1Sb549FvpJt

Comment: This example only covers using a scrollview, not a listview.

Comment: @strange how does this work for listview as should not have listview within scrollview

Answer (score 1):

You can find implementations at these two pages:

- https://github.com/LarsWerkman/QuickReturnListView
- https://github.com/ManuelPeinado/QuickReturnHeader

And I suggest you to read the following blog post which discusses when to use and not to use this ui pattern: http://www.androiduipatterns.com/2012/08/an-emerging-ui-pattern-quick-return.html