# Show Bottom Buttons Bar in ListView while scrolling up and hide when scrolling down

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I have a huge listview, with a Bottom bar with three buttons in them. Now, my question is, Is there a way to hide the bottom bar (With Buttons) while scrolling down, and show them up while scrolling up the listview?

Just like how Google+ Handles in the iOS App.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found another link with the facebook pattern, [Android Listview Floating First Row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15464649/android-listview-floating-first-row)

It has one answer, 
It's called the Quick Return pattern, and Roman's explained it in detail along with an example here: https://plus.google.com/u/0/+RomanNurik/posts/1Sb549FvpJt

Comment: As a matter of fact, neither of the solution are actual answer to this question. Nurik's sol is an extension of scrollviews and the solution can't be used here for this question.