# Android: listview scroll hide option view like twitter or facebook?

Tags: android, performance, android-listview

There is option view below the action bar like twitter. While scrolling up the option, view will slide／hide accrodingly. Is there any example for this? How to do this precisely? Do I have to do this with OnTouchListener? please help.

Comment: Have you try OnScrollListener to detect ScrollUp and ScrollDown even like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17017477/1621500)

Comment: @Jackie ya i did that, but seem like not precise and efficient. because my item height is too long. have to wait until entire single item scrolled up only execute the statement.

Comment: This might be answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15464649/android-listview-floating-first-row, which you can check out the sample app from: https://code.google.com/p/romannurik-code/source/browse/misc/scrolltricks/

Comment: You can check this git [repo.](https://github.com/amalChandran/twitterListView)