# Android: Facebook menu Show and Hide on list scroll

Tags: android, facebook, android-layout, android-listview

Which module I can use for creating menu like facebook "Status, Photo, CheckIn" which is open on List scroll up and hide on Scroll down. Is there any API available for it or any solution with sliding drawer.
its good if solution available with top menu on top.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

copied from "strange" answer on [Android Listview Floating First Row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15464649/android-listview-floating-first-row) .

It's called the Quick Return pattern, and Roman's explained it in detail along with an example here:
https://plus.google.com/u/0/+RomanNurik/posts/1Sb549FvpJt