# Android GridView Floating Footer like Facebook Feed

Tags: android, facebook, gridview

I'm trying to find the best way to approach implementing Facebook like floating last row on Grid view.
when scrolling down, the status-photo-checkin disappear to allow more space for the list, and when scrolling up it appears again. anyone has an idea how can I implement this or direct me to an existing component/library?

I have seen the post [Android Listview Floating First Row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15464649/android-listview-floating-first-row?lq=1) and try the Quick Return pattern: https://plus.google.com/u/0/+RomanNurik/posts/1Sb549FvpJt
But it does not work for GridView.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this QuickReturn library I wrote.
https://github.com/lawloretienne/QuickReturn

It even has an example of how its done in Facebook.